# Possilble to auto open a downloaded word document downloaded in browser

Tags: asp.net

The requirement is sent a Word document from browser, and automatically open it on MS Word so that then can view and edit the Word document.

The only solution I can found require the end user to click a dialogue Window in order to open a Word document in Office when the document is download from browser.

Is this the only way, that the user has to click a dialogue Window before Office can open the downloaded Word document?

[image: Browser Dialog]

It kinds of make sense for security reason to not let browser automatically execute an local application (Word.exe) on the local machine, but I still want to confirm that.

If the answer is yes, then I would like to know how to do that?

Edit: I just found out that you have to use `inline` instead of `Attachement`, otherwise it will always ask for the option event the browsers are setup properly.

```
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline;filename=clientquotes.docx");
```

After made that change, browser will auto open the Word document without asking for action.

Comment: What's your question again? I'm confused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to change the behaviour of your browser to automatically open downloaded files. As far I'm aware its pretty painless process when it comes to Firefox and Google Chrome, however on IE it's not as simple.

**Firefox**

**Changing download actions**

This will not affect media embedded in a web page - only links to the files themselves.

1. Click the menu button [image] Menu and choose `Options`
2. Select the `Applications` panel.
3. The Applications panel will display. Select the type of file for which you want to change the default action.
4. The Action column will give you a drop-down menu, with options on action to take, whenever you click that type of file.

[image]

- **Alwaysask:** will prompt you to select what action you want Firefox to take when you click on that type of file. This can be useful if Firefox is automatically saving a file type or is always opening it with a certain program and you want to be asked what to do.
- **Save File:** will always save the file to your computer using the Downloads window, whenever you click that type of file.
- Open the file with an application or plugin of your choosing.

  5. Click `Ok` to close the options window after making changes

**Adding download actions**

1. On the web, find a link to a file matching the type you want to add.
2. Click on the file link to download it.
3. Select how you want Firefox to handle the file:

   **Open with:** Saves the file to a temporary folder and opens it in the default application for that file type. To select an application, click Browse....

   ```
   Do not choose Firefox to always open a certain file type, as doing so can cause 
   a problem where Firefox repeatedly opens empty tabs or windows after you click on a link.
   ```

   **Save file:** Saves the file to the download folder (specified in the Firefox General panel).

   In the Opening file window, check mark **Do this automatically for files like this from now on.**

[image]

Click `Ok`.

```
Is Do this automatically for files like this from now on disabled? 
This can happen if the website's server incorrectly specifies the 
Internet Media type of the file. It also can happen if the server assigns 
"Content-Disposition: attachment" to the file.
```

**[Reference](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/change-firefox-behavior-when-open-file)**

**Google Chrome**

If you want certain types of file always to open after they've finished downloading, click the arrow next to the file button in the downloads bar and select Always open files of this type.

**[Reference](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95759?hl=en-GB)**

**IE**

From what I can gather for IE you will have to change the registry keys. You can refer to this **[link](http://jwcooney.com/2014/03/31/remove-internet-explorer-open-or-save-popup/)** for further information.

I hope this answers your question.

Comment: Thank Lzzy, works brilliantly! I am more concern about IE and I have to support for version for older IE as well, but the fact that browsers can indeed doing what I want it good enough. It is hardly a surprise that IE is doing something different.